# UnicodeDecodeError when I try to install ordered-set

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to install ordered-set via pip, with setup.py and using wheel, but all three times I got an exception:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python 3.6.3\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, 
in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcd in position 35: 
invalid continuation byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "c:\python 3.6.3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main 
status = self.run(options, args)
 File "c:\python 3.6.3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run wb.build(autobuilding=True)
 File "c:\python 3.6.3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
 File "c:\python 3.6.3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
 File "c:\python 3.6.3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 634, in _prepare_file
abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
 File "c:\python 3.6.3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 129, in prep_for_dist
self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
 File "c:\python 3.6.3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 439, in run_egg_info
command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
 File "c:\python 3.6.3\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
File "c:\python 3.6.3\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
return s.decode('utf_8')

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcd in position 35: 
invalid continuation byte
```

What it could depends on? What should I do to solve that problem?

I have the same problem during installing stix and cybox packages.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update pip to beta version `pip install -U --pre pip`

If it does't help try using easy_install

Another solution:

> run a new cmd.exe console chcp it will show the system default code,
>   for example 936. open Lib/site-package/pip/compat/**init**.py around
>   75 line, change return s.decode('utf_8') to return s.decode('cp936')

It's just a workaround from https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4251

Comment: It's strange but I haven't got a **compat** in **Lib/site-package/pip**

Comment: @kosmo_tony what pip version are u using? Your path should be `c:\python 3.6.3\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py`

Comment: I use pip 18.0 version. So if I try to go `c:\python 3.6.3\lib\site-packages\pip\compat` in cmd I get the message **system can not find the specified path**

Comment: Are u sure, this location what in your error message: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python 3.6.3\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, `

Comment: I'm absolutely sure, by path `c:\python 3.6.3\lib\site-packages\pip` there are 3 folders: **__pycache__**, **_internal**, **_vendor** and also 2 scripts: **__init__.py** (consists of 1 line with the pip version only) and **__main__.py**. And nothing else.